# Why for n in 1:0 in iterates 2 times in R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, iteration

Forgive my ignorance but I would appreciate if someone explains me why I obtain this result.  I expect the result to be empty because I wanted to iterate over the number of rows and the number of rows is 0. Instead, it iterates 2 times:

```
> df<-data.frame()
> nrow(df)
[1] 0
> for(n in 1:nrow(df)){ cat("foo")}
foofoo
```

In addition, what is the correct expression of iteration over the number of row of a data.frame?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the comments.
I replaced `1:nrow(df)` with
 `seq_len(nrow(df))` 
and it works. 1:0 is actually containing two elements **1** and **0** and it iterates over those elements:

```
> 1:0
[1] 1 0
```

Comment: For this very reason, `1:nrow(df)` shouldn't be used. Use `seq_len(nrow(df))` instead.

Comment: @nicola you should post that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

A range X:Y gives you a vector from X to Y, inclusive of X and Y. If X > Y, the list is decreasing. In your case, you are asking for a list from 1:0, which has two elements, 1 and 0.

Comment: Make that NROW() and it won't spit out an error when it encounters a one dimensional object.

Comment: "If Y > X, the list is decreasing" - shouldn't that be "if X > Y"?